# Omnet Tkenv run config for multiple parameters: executing only the first value of parameter

Tags: c++, omnet++

My ini code for the config is as:

```
[Config BR54MBPS1MS]
description = "at 54MBPS with SI 1ms for 1250 Bytes with all time interval"
repeat = 2
sim-time-limit = 1 min
**.scalar-recording = true
**.vector-recording = false
**.host1.udpApp[0].messageLength = 1250B
**.wlan*.bitrate = 54Mbps
**.host1.udpApp[*].sendInterval = ${interval = 100..1200 step 100} us
**.vector-recording = false
output-scalar-file = 54Mbps/${configname}54Mbps${interval}us.sca
```

and I want to run it for all given intervals from 100 us to 1200 us with a gap of 100 us (at 100, 200, 300 ... us) in omnet tkenv or gui. The only option I read for it is by run it through run configuration as: [image]

The problem is that, it runs only for 100us successfully, generates the output sca file and terminates the process. I am not able to figure out the reason for not running the for the next send interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run all combinations of `sendInterval` values you should write `*` (asterisk) in `Run number` field and select `Command line` interface. Multiple runs are not possible when `Tcl/Tk user interface` is selected.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was going with * initially but at some point I changed it to save time in simulations and now need to verify again.

Comment: but there is another problem in one of my simulation. The number of run is set to 0 by default in ini and in run configuration, if I give * then it results in an error :-  **Run number(1) is greater then the number of runs(1) supported by current configuration**

Comment: Tcl/Tk user interface is probably selected. Multiple runs (e.g. Run number=*) are only possible in Command Line interface.