# Multiple Simulation Runs (OMnet++)

Tags: simulation, omnet++

I implemented a 100 km long highway scenario using Veins Framework for OMNET++.

- In order to get more reliable results, how many simulation runs are required for each set of experiment ?
- How can we define and control the number of simulation runs?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 3):

**Quicker simulations:**

You can make your simulations run faster in 3 possible ways:

- run sumo without the `gui` by starting the `./sumo-launchd.py` excluding `sumo-gui` in the end and writing only `sumo`.
- run simulations using `Cmdenv` and not `Tkenv`,
- compile your Veins project code in in `release mode`. You can achieve that by doing: 
  -`make MODE=release -j <number-of-cores>`

These steps will improve simulation run-time up to 50%.

In the [Veins FAQ](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/faq/) you have the following questions:

> I've launched a simulation in the OMNeT++ TkEnv; why is it running so
>   awefully slow?
>
> I've launched a simulation in the OMNeT++ Cmdenv; can I speed it up
>   further?

There are some suggestions given in the FAQ which might help you run simulations quicker.

---

**Number of simulation runs:**

As far as the number of simulation runs is concerned, it is hard to tell. You can use *confidence intervals* for your results to see how fine-grained they are; In any case I would suggest starting with 5 repetitions.

---

**Automatic control of simulation runs:**

This can be accomplished using `repeat` parameter in the `.ini` file as it is explained [here](http://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec347).

On how to do that from the **OMNeT++ IDE** follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232641/4786271) (note the comments as well).

To run parallel simulations through the **command line**, follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572095/4786271).

Answer (score 1):

- a) This is an open ended question as you have not defined what 'more reliable' means. To get a more reliable result, you need more runs. That's all that can be said.
- b) use `repeat = 2` in the ini file to get two repetitions

I'm also suggesting reading the manual's corresponding chapter: 
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec341

(Chapter 10 is also related to your question)